# Why don't these two code snippets behave equivalently?

Tags: c++, if-statement, equivalent, equivalence

I have the following function (much simplified for the case of an example):

```
bool _move (class Square * const cpOldSquare, class Square * const cpNewSquare, const bool & rcOverride = false) {
    if (rcOverride ? true :
        (!!cpOldSquare->mupChesspiece
            && cpOldSquare->mupChesspiece->mcColour == _player
            && ISINSIDE(cpOldSquare->mupChesspiece->mContinuation.mrcvcpGetList(), cpNewSquare)))
        // do something
```

Now, I call this function from the below piece of code. I introduced the `rcOverride` bool in order to optimise the `_move` function, because, logically speaking, all the conditions of the if statement were met when calling the function from this environment, so I did not need to test for those again.

```
for (const auto * const & rcpcChesspiece : _chessboard.mPieces.mrcvcpGetList()) {
        if (rcpcChesspiece->mcColour != _player) continue;
        for (auto * const & rcpSquare : rcpcChesspiece->mContinuation.mrcvcpGetList())
            if (_move(rcpcChesspiece->mpSquare, rcpSquare, true))
                // do something
    }
```

I got a segfault, however, which I've been able to pinpoint to come from the third condition being untrue (the `ISINSIDE` macro, defined as `#define ISINSIDE(x,y) (std::find(x.begin(), x.end(), y) != x.end())`).

The programme behaves correctly if I remove the `true` override, allowing it to test for the third condition, and subsequently not run the code inside the if-statement.

You might not agree with the way I handled this optimisation effort, but looking at all the variables, where they come from (logically speaking -- take a look at the range-based for-loops in the second block of code), I must conclude that they should behave ***equivalently***. `ISINSIDE` must always evaluate to `true`, right? Can you see where the difference in behaviour comes from?

Comment: With "they should behave equivalently", I meant the code resp. with and without the `true` parameter included in the function call.

Comment: `if (rcOverride ? true :
        (!!cpOldSquare->...` is a difficult to read code, it can be better `if (rcOverride ||
        (!!cpOldSquare->...`

Comment: `const bool & rcOverride` - bool by reference, really?

Comment: You show one code snippet which defines a function named `_move`. Then you show another code snippet which calls the `_move` function. They do different things, they aren't equivalent. Please try to create a couple of proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: Regarding e.g. `class Square * const cpOldSquare`, there are two things: First of all you don't need the `class` keyword here. Second, you make the *pointer* constant, not the structure it points to. That's not very common.

Comment: Why are you using a macro at all?

Comment: While there just isn't enough detail for us to really do anything but guess, a couple of possible guesses could involve you modifying the container you iterating over; Returning objects by value instead of by reference; Whatever happens in "do something"; And many other possibilities.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @237K thanks for the suggestion! It makes a lot more sense to do the override that way, without the ternary operator!

Comment: @237K, it's good practice to pass by const reference, if you're not going to modify it anyways. For consistency's sake, I prefer to always do so

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, "They do different things, they aren't equivalent." Please read the comment where I mentioned which two code snippets I was talking about: The one with the true parameter and the one without, both calling the exact same move function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, elaborated type specifiers add clarity imo, so I'll keep using them, thanks! As for the constant pointer: that was deliberate. I won't modify the pointer itself, but I will modify the square. If it *can* be `const`, it *should* be `const`.

Comment: @DavisHerring, the simple std::find function is not worth creating a whole separate bool function for. That just increases the function call overhead; this is way more efficient and compact.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thanks for the suggestions! If you tried to read my post, I'm sure you'd've seen that the contents of the `// do something` are completely irrelevant to the equivalency of the code. The issue is the `ISINSIDE` evaluating to `false` whilst logically speaking, looking at the origins of all variables, it ***should*** evaluate to `true`.

Comment: `if (x ? true : something_else)` should be written `if (x || something_else)`.

Comment: Thanks! That suggestion was already made by user 273K, though. I'll mark your comment as a duplicate ;)

Comment: @JoligeJ: The phrase “a whole separate bool function” suggests some sort of complexity that the macro lacks, but a macro is no shorter and rather more complicated (especially cognitively).  Anyone concerned about function-call overhead is inlining, so there isn’t any for something so trivial.  (Elaborated type specifiers are also way more subtle than one would think; they’re best avoided when possible.)

Comment: Usually when you see differences when logically there shouldn't be any, that's a symptom of undefined behavior.  All you need to do is find what's causing it, and it could be something completely unrelated to what you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Unwrapping the boilerplate, the code is testing whether the container

```
rcpcChesspiece->mpSquare->mupChesspiece->mContinuation.mrcvcpGetList()
```

contains `rcpSquare`. By virtue of the range-for loop, we know that it should be contained in

```
rcpcChesspiece->mContinuation.mrcvcpGetList()
```

With the code presented, there is not enough information to conclude those containers must always be equal or that a member of one is always a member of the other.

Comment: To clarify: every chesspiece contains a raw ptr to its square, and every square contains a `unique_ptr` to the chesspiece that's on top; if there isn't any, it's a `nullptr`. Now whenever moving or undoing a move (which is done by swapping `unique_ptr`s btw), the chesspieces moved have their pointer to the square updated automatically. I believe the issue doesn't lie here. The same function gets called regardless of which chesspiece is moved. For one specific piece, however, the `ISINSIDE` macro evaluates to false, which is ignored when using the override, which in turn causes a segfault.

Comment: Now, logically speaking, if every square correctly points to the chesspiece on it (which I'm not so worried about as that would mess up the whole printing of the board if it weren't correct) *and* every chesspiece correctly points to the corresponding square, the `true` override shouldn't make a difference at all. There is always one combination of values for which `ISINSIDE` evaluates to false, and I'm not sure how to go about solving this.